# smarty error where there is no errors

Tags: php, smarty

I get this error *sometimes*

> [28-Mar-2011 14:22:20] PHP Notice:  function call 'get_template_vars' is unknown or deprecated. in /home/jordan/public_html/includes/smrty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_wrapper.php on line 57

but I do not use this function in **ANY** php file, and it does not exist in any php file in the project (opened all php files and with `np++` and searched through all of them)

However, why does this error appears in the error log, and how to fix it?

I use `smarty 3.0`

Thanks

Comment: Seems like Smarty itself is using the method (assuming that path points to a smarty lib folder) : /home/jordan/public_html/includes/smrty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_wrapper.php on line 57

Comment: Do you use the very last stable version of Smarty (3.0.7) ? http://www.smarty.net/download

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure you are using the most recent, stable version of Smarty. The error you are getting is from Smarty trying to convert older, Smarty2 style functions to the new Smarty3 style. This could be in your code or in template tags, plugins, etc. To find the culprit, try throwing in a debug_backtrace() in the the convert() method of smarty_internal_wrapper.php